# Eclipse: which plugins for HTML & Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

Which plugins do you use for editing (with syntax highlighting) HTML & Javascript in Eclipse 3.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spket](http://spket.com/) is a great plugin for JavaScript.  For HTML, I normally just use the default XML/HTML editor that comes with [Eclipse WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) which is good enough for my purposes.  Depending on which Eclipse distro you downloaded, you may already have this

Answer (score 2):

I've heard Aptana is great, but I have not used it personally.

Comment: I've used it and I definitely liked it.  I used the standalone, however, as I'm not a heavy Eclipse user.  The functionality was great, but it seemed a little slow, (mainly startup time) and I now prefer just using Emacs for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)