# HTML, Javascript, PHP and Actionscript all in one Eclipse install (2010)

Tags: php, javascript, html, eclipse

I just wanted to poll the community and see which plugins people are currently using to get all of these different technologies running in Eclipse.

I saw this thread which mentioned Spket & WPT: [Eclipse: which plugins for HTML & Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575617/eclipse-which-plugins-for-html-javascript)
But I noticed that Spket doesn't seem to have been updated since October of 2009 so I'm wondering if it's still a good tool to use.

I'm not sure what would be best for PHP since it seems like some of the tools are disjointed at the moment.

For Actionscript I know I can just install the latest Flash Builder plugin and be done.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I use [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) for PHP development on Eclipse. I recommend you to take a look at it.

[Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) is a good tool for HTML, CSS and JavaScript. You can install it as a plugin. Features: HTML, CSS, and JavaScript Code Assist, JavaScript Debugging, JavaScript Libraries and DOM Outline.

You can install Aptana Studio on a current Eclipse with PDT, and it works like a charm. I really liked Aptana's features for HTML, CSS and JavaScript. PDT + Aptana is probably the best all-in-one Eclipse experience for web-development with PHP.

ActionScript is based on the same ECMA standard as JavaScript, so I guess most of Aptana's JavaScript features will be available for ActionScript.

You can also try the new [Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/heliosr).

Comment: after so much searching I've finally settled on just running Eclipse with Aptana and Flash Builder as plugins.